# How to remove a digit pattern at the beginning of a string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like so, "123.234.567 Remove numbers in this string". The output should be "Remove numbers in this string".

The digits in this string follow the pattern xx.xxx.xxxxx...(digits followed by a period), but the number of periods and digits between each period is not static. here are a couple examples. xx.xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxx, x.xx.xxxx.xxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxx, x.xx.xxxxxx, etc.

How can I remove these digits followed by periods in regex?

So far I have something like this:

```
patt = re.compile('(\s*)[0-9].[0-9]*.[0-9]*(\s*)')
```

But this only works for a specific format.

Comment: You have to escape `.` if you want to match it literally. Otherwise it matches any character.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The title asks how to remove the pattern from the beginning of the string, but the question seems to ask how to write the pattern. Which is it?

Comment: It is not clear from your question what your input is, what you want to remove, and output would be. Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: `[0-9]` only matches a single digit. If you want to match any number of digits, use `[0-9]+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `^` to match the beginning of the string.
- Use `\d+` to match any number of digits.
- Use `\.` to match a literal `.` character
- Put `\.\d+` in a group with `()` so you can quantify it to match any number of them.
- Use `re.sub()` to replace it with an empty string to remove the match.
- Use a raw string so you can put literal backslashes in the regexp without having to escape them.

```
patt = re.compile(r's*^\d+(?:\.\d+)+\s*')
string = patt.sub('', string)
```